# How to include jquery plugin in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic3

I'm trying to implement jQuery FloatLabel in my ionic app -> https://github.com/m10l/FloatLabel.js/tree/master

I used that plugin because that plugin also was implemented in a web version, so to be uniform in design.

I included that inside src/index.html with jquery

```
<link href="assets/js/jquery.FloatLabel/jquery.FloatLabel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.FloatLabel/jquery.FloatLabel.js"></script>
```

I want to execute this script on page load

```
$( '.js-float-label-wrapper' ).FloatLabel();
```

Here's my src/index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="assets/js/jquery.FloatLabel/jquery.FloatLabel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.FloatLabel/jquery.FloatLabel.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $( '.js-float-label-wrapper' ).FloatLabel();
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works on web version but not in ionic. How do I implement that on ionic?

I want it like this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/acrmktq3/

Comment: do you get any error on console? i guess you should call floatlabel function of document ready

Comment: No console errors, I already did that, do you use ionic ?

Comment: yes i use ionic and i haven't faced such kind of problem. Didi you get any error in console?

Comment: there are no console errors, did you try to use external jquery plugin in ionic?

Comment: yes i have used it multiple times in multiple projects. Let me try it again.

Comment: can you help me with my issue please? I want to implement like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/acrmktq3/  using ionic

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue, already installed jquery just need to get the plugin correctly working

Answer (score 0):

link jquery.js in your index.html:

```
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

run in node:

```
npm install jquery
```

and import it in your page like:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your JavaScript code in the bottom of your body like this:

```
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $( '.js-float-label-wrapper' ).FloatLabel();
  </script>
</body>
```

You're addng it before your app initialization, the `main.js` wasn't even loaded and you've already executed your code, so using it on the bottom of your code should do the trick.

Also, have you ever tried using this FloatLabel in a Ionic application? Since the page may not be loaded and the code already had been executed you need it to be more "Angular way". You can use it inside the component that's having the floating label, just use this to be able to use JQuery inside your component:

```
declare var $: any; // declare this bellow your page imports to be able to use jQuery
```

Or you can try Ionic floating Label, so there's no need to have JQuery and other library inside your project, even if it's not "uniform" design

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label color="primary" floating>Floating Label</ion-label>
  <!-- Use the floating attribute to have your label to float when you focus on the input -->
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its not working, I tried to import like this `import * as FloatLabel from '../../assets/js/jquery.FloatLabel/jquery.FloatLabel.js';` and use it inside `ionViewDidLoad() { $('.js-float-label-wrapper').FloatLabel(); }`  but I've got an error `ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_jquery__(...).FloatLabel is not a function`